# save plots made by loop in a file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making ggplots using for loop function and wanted to save all the plots in a file for using in ppt format.

The code I am using is

```
for(i in 1:28) {
  plot_i <- ggplot(Num, aes(Num[,i]))+ geom_histogram(fill="skyblue", col="Blue")+
          ggtitle(names(Num)[i])+theme_classic()

  ggplot2::ggsave(filename = paste0("plot_",i,".png"),plot_i, path = "E:/Folder1")

}
```

However when i open the saved png file only 1 out of all 28 graphs is visible
When i check if the graphs are actually made or not all the graphs are being made in r studio

```
for(i in 1:28) {
  print(ggplot(Num, aes(Num[,i]))+ geom_histogram(fill="skyblue", col="Blue")+
          ggtitle(names(Num)[i]))+theme_classic()
}
```

This codes helps me in viewing all the plots, but if i have to save it i have to go one by one which is very lengthy process. it will be useful for me if i could save the plots in .doc or .ppt file
I have checked similar questions here but the solutions given are not working.

Comment: Try using `dev.off()` as the last command within the loop. It closes the active graph and then does the entire process for the next graph.

Comment: dev.off shouldn’t be needed with ggsave. Are you sure that’s it @kashj

Comment: @kashj....i have tried..but same result...only 1 graph coming i the png file, all others are missing

Comment: @MrFlick.....yes you got it right. I want each plots in png format in individual file but i am getting only one file i.e plot_24. and it has only one graph

Comment: insert `print(plot_i)` command before `ggsave` command?

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks for that. I was not sure.

Comment: @monte... it worked....i got all the 28 graphs as png file in the folder....Thanks

Comment: @monte do you know when that’s needed when the plot is being passed explicitly to ggsave as a parameter? It seems like that should take care of the print().

Comment: @MrFlick i have added the answer, with more detailed explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you had shared:

```r
for(i in 1:28) {
  plot_i <- ggplot(Num, aes(Num[,i]))+ geom_histogram(fill="skyblue", col="Blue")+
          ggtitle(names(Num)[i])+theme_classic()

  ggplot2::ggsave(filename = paste0("plot_",i,".png"),plot_i, path = "E:/Folder1")

}
```

You are storing the plot object in the variable `plot_i`. You are not printing those plots. You need to insert, `print(plot_i)` statement before saving the plot using `ggplot` as follows:

```r
for(i in 1:28) {
  plot_i <- ggplot(Num, aes(Num[,i]))+ geom_histogram(fill="skyblue", col="Blue")+
          ggtitle(names(Num)[i])+theme_classic()

  print(plot_i)

  ggplot2::ggsave(filename = paste0("plot_",i,".png"),plot_i, path = "E:/Folder1")

}
```

The reason why you need to print is because, `ggsave` defaults to save the last displayed plot, and by printing you actually display on the Rs display devices. In simpler words this is what `ggsave` does:

```r
png('file_name.png') #it opens a graphics devices, can be other also like jpeg
print(plot_i) #displays the plot on graphics device
dev.off() #closes the graphic device
```

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. You only need the `print()` if you aren't passing the plot directly to `ggsave()`. This works perfectly fine for me: `for(i in 1:3) {p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mtcars[,i])) + geom_histogram(); ggsave(paste("plot", i, ".png"), p)}` Does it not for you? I think the OP must be leaving something out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this once. It does not involve `ggplot2` though.

```
for(i in 1:28){
   jpeg(filename= paste("E:/Folder1/plot_",i,".png", sep= "")
   plot_i <- ggplot(Num, aes(Num[,i]))+ geom_histogram(fill="skyblue", col="Blue")+
                    ggtitle(names(Num)[i])+theme_classic()
   print(plot_i)
   dev.off()
}
```

Comment: _n.b._ when plotting multiple objects (like 2 or more DFs or similar), store them in a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023427/applying-some-functions-to-multiple-objects) and then [lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412460/r-using-lapply-to-save-plots) a function over them.

Answer (score -1):

`ggplot` uses lazy evaluation and a `for` loop doesn't `force()` evaluation of your loop index.  `lapply` does.  So change your `for` loop to `lapply`.

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63028719/adding-geom-in-a-for-loop/63029084#63029084) gives more details.

Comment: But the ggsave should force the evaluation and that’s inside the loop. I’m not sure this is the case here.

Comment: @MrFlick.  That was my first thought also.  But, in the basence of a MWE, I took OP at their word.  But using `mtcars %>% group_split(cyl)` to create a list of data frames, their code works as for me: three different plots in three different files.  Perhaps the issue lay elsewhere.